# Forbidden !! while trying to access the hereapi traces service

Tags: rest, postman, here-api, bearer-token

I've been working on here API from past one week, I've tested the geofencing and other rest services. I am trying to work on tracking, Where we have to generate a token by giving all the valid credentials. At last, I've got the token as well but when am trying to access the traces one for which the endpoint URL is

```
    https://tracking.api.here.com/traces/v2/{trackingid}
```

here I've given the **trackingid(deviceid)** which I've used to generate an access token  and included this token as a bearer in authorization I am using postman to test these, my token is valid for only 23 hours

```
    Authorization    Bearer {mytoken}
```

As mentioned I've also provided this **x-request-id**, I've no idea regarding this x-request-id but came to know about this from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433258/what-is-the-x-request-id-http-header) and tried to generate uuid and use it for x-request-id

```
    x-request-id    5506b7d0-2fe6-4967-8ad8-cf0f08fdedbf
```

And I am receiving the response as

```
    {
      "code": 403,
      "id": "5506b7d0-2fe6-4967-8ad8-cf0f08fdedbf",
      "message": "Forbidden",
      "error": "Forbidden\n\nThe account does not have the correct 
                privileges\n"
    }
```

The similar case even when I am trying to access the allotted geofences for that device and how many devices are in that particular geofence. I've read about whitelisting but whatever the service I am requesting for is not on their list. My account was a 90days free trial account

I am new to this hereapi Kindly correct me if I am doing anything wrong.
Kindly Help me out with this issue

Thanks in advance
--Meghana Goud

Comment: Make sure bearer/token is generated for `https://tracking.api.here.com`. If we generate token in local environment and try to access other(production etc..) end points, it will throw 403 Forbidden. And try to give  `bearer` instead of 'Bearer'. Might help you.

Comment: yeah my bearer token is generated for `https://tracking.api.here.com`  and I am trying to access `https://tracking.api.here.com/traces/v2/{trackingid}`, 'Bearer' it's formed in postman header when  I select Bearer Token as Authorization @Veeresh

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out, I'll include the details here follow the step by step process as mentioned in the documentation 
refer this [HERE Tracking | API Reference](https://tracking.here.com/documentation/index.html)

And follow the step by step process as mentioned in this documentation

1. The first one, you'll get your bearer token from this endpoint URL `https://tracking.api.here.com/users/v2/login` which is post 
   method and set its **Content-Type to application/json** and provide the username and password in JSON format and send a **POST** request to it

   ```
   EndpointURL      :https://tracking.api.here.com/users/v2/login
   Headers          :{"Content-Type":"application/json"}
   Input            :{"email":"XXXXXX", "password":"XXXX"}
   Expected Response:{
                      "userId": "XXXXXX",
                      "accessToken": "XXXXX",
                      "tokenType": "bearer",
                      "expiresIn": 86399,
                      "refreshToken": "XXX"
                     }
   ```

   the token is valid for only 24 hours. Now use this token for all the rest services you want to access from here-API
2. Now I would like to get the traces of my device using this endpointURL `https://tracking.api.here.com/traces/v2/{trackingid}?count=1` , send a get request to this endpointURL by giving your trackingID, I repeat TrackingID is different from your deviceId TrackingId will be `HERE-XXX(UUIDv4)` whereas deviceId will be `XXXX(UUIDv4)`
   now set the authorization to Bearer Token and pass an x-request-id which is a `UUIDv4`
   Your request should look like

   ```
   EndpointURL      :https://tracking.api.here.com/traces/v2/{trackingid}?count=1
   Headers          :{"Authorization":"Bearer XXXXXX","x-request-id":"XXXX(UUIDv4)"}
   Expected Response:{
                      "count": 1,
                      "data": [
                                 {

                                 "position": {
                                        "lat": 17.44936354,
                                        "lng": 78.36296417,
                                        "accuracy": 45,
                                        "alt": 539
                                   },
                                "timestamp": 1531462419813,
                                "payload": {
                                          "refAppData": 
                                              {
                                                 "batteryState": {
                                                    "charging": false,
                                                    "level": 52,
                                                    "temperature": 25
                                                   }
                                               }
                                           }
                                }
                             ],
                       "pageToken": "1531462359711"
                      }
   ```

   3. In order to update any data from your device, you'll require your device token which is generated from this endpoint URL`https://tracking.api.here.com/v2/token` you'll get your access token by OAuth1.o Authorization give the respected values as mentioned in the documentation. you'll get the response as

      `{
        "accessToken": "XXXXXX",
        "expiresIn": 86399
      }`

Similarly, you can test other services,
Hope this helps

*Meghana*