# How is x-requestid populated?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Please see the code below, which is similar to some code I am looking at:

```
 [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Create([FromHeader(Name = "x-requestid")] string requestId)
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(Person person, [FromHeader(Name = "x-requestid")] string requestId)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string test = "got here";
            }
            return View();
        }
```

requestId is always null.  How is requestId populated?

I have read lots of questions over the last two hours e.g. this one: [What is the X-REQUEST-ID http header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433258/what-is-the-x-request-id-http-header).  An answerer to another question suggesting installing the following Nuget package:

```
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.ASPNetCore
```

However, this made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

In general the "x-*" headers are [non-standard ones](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-8.3.1).

That particular one is probably coincidentally used within Application Insights to uniquely identify a request, but it's unlikely to be sending requests to your server including it.

Whatever client is sending requests to your server has to be explicitly adding that header for you to receive it there; it's not part of any standard HTTP request.

Comment: Can you provide a example how is added?

Comment: It would be client-specific, but if you had say a C# `HttpClient` in your client application, there would probably be the creation of an `HttpRequestMessage`, and something like `requestMessage.Headers.Add("x-requestid", Guid.NewGuid().ToString())`, or the `HttpClient` might be created with a custom message handler that automatically adds that to each message (the same way).

Comment: Thanks.  I tested that and it worked as expected.  I will accept when it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

You are bound to request header with name "x-requestid", but it should be called "X-Request-ID". Just try:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get([FromHeader(Name = "x-request-id")] string requestId)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I am as sure as I can be that it should be: x-requestid.

Comment: Anyway, you can check all headers in request in action method `this.Request.Headers`.