# Performance testing of salesforce application using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am trying to performance test the salesforce application using JMeter. All the requests has X-SFDC-Request-Id in the request headers. I couldn't correlate those header values from any of the previous request response. Is there any logic to implement the same using JMeter, as Salesforce does? Please assist

Thanks in advance, 
Anto

Answer (score 1):

Looking into [What is the X-REQUEST-ID http header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433258/what-is-the-x-request-id-http-header) is seems that you need to pass some random value, it will allow the server to identify the failing request or for [load balancing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)) or whatever else reason.

So my expectation is that you can send something random or unique using [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) or [__UUID()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID) functions as this is not something you should be correlating.

[image]

Check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction/) article to learn more about JMeter Functions concept

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. I will try the same